# How to prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{(x^n)}dx=0$?

Tags: calculus

> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{(x^n)}dx=0$$

How to prove it? It seems that the integral cannot be evaluated.

Comment: This is unclear. Do you mean $\sin(x^n)$ or $(\sin(x))^n = \sin^n(x)$?

Comment: @HenryTuring the former one

Comment: In fact, the integrals $I_n=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{(x^n)}\,dx$ can be evaluated using special functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici could you please be more specific or give me some links about it?

Comment: It is really very complex and totally out off topic. Using WA, type for example **integrate sin(x^6) from x=0 to x=pi/2**

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**

By reduction formula we have:

$$\int \sin^n(x)\ dx = \frac{\sin^{n+1}(x)}{n\cos(x)} - \frac{1}{n}\int \frac{sin^n(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\ dx$$

And you can clearly see that the limit for $n\to +\infty$ makes all zero.

**Case 2**

$$\int \sin(x^n)\ dx$$

Change of variable $$x^n = t ~~~ dx = \frac{\sqrt[n]{t}}{nt}$$

$$\int\sin(x^n)\ dx = \int \sin(t) \frac{\sqrt[n]{t}}{nt}\ dx$$

Again the limit makes zero everything.

Comment: The $\sin{t}\frac{\sqrt[n]{t}}{t}$ is not bounded. How can the limit make it zero?

Comment: @闫嘉琦 The limit is zero! You can check it with whatever rule or method.

Comment: Henry Turing: the limit is indeed zero as $n \to \infty$.  The question is, how are you going to prove it beyond an exclamation point?

Comment: @HenryTuring a I see. Split the interval into $[0,1]$ and $[1,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, the first integral turns to zero, then by your method, the second one is bounded hence $1/n$ makes it zero.